# Tell Atom+Hydrogen to look in virtual enviromnment for packages

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtual-environment, hydrogen

I'm completely new to this. I have set up Python3 and Atom and installed Hydrogen for Atom so I can run each line of my code and see the output.

I have set up a virtual environment and added packages to it.

My problem is that inside my Atom .py file, when I say `import numpy as np` for example, it tells me that the module is not found. So I think it is looking in some default place and not inside my virtual environment. Which makes sense as I don't know how to tell it to look inside the virtual environment.

I know that inside terminal I can load the virtual environment and then call the .py file from there and it will look in the right place. However that is not what I want to do. I want to be able to tell it to look in the virtual environment in the top line of the code and execute using Hydrogen, and then load the packages I want using Hydrogen, and then carry on with each line of code after that using Hydrogen.

Can someone tell me how to tell python to look in a specific virtual environment for the duration of the .py file that is being developed/executed?

Comment: See also https://github.com/nteract/hydrogen/issues/243#issuecomment-203686955

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62202986/setting-up-a-python-virtual-environment-with-hydrogen-in-atom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For our purpose here virtual environments are just changing the search path of your interpreter.

Therefore if we want to search in a given virtual environment we can just add the path of this environment to our search path, which you can do in python by using

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/virtualenv')
```

The path to your virtual environment depends on how you configured it, but usually they are stored in a subfolder of your home directory called `.virtualenvs`, so this would probably look like

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/username/.virtualenvs/EnvName/')

# rest of code
```

Also note that this does not change your system path or pythonpath environment variables, and therefore only lasts for the duration of this python interpreter instance.

Comment: Ok so this worked, only thing is that my packages were in the /home/username/virtualEnvName/lib/python3.6/site-packages folder and I had to add that exact folder and not the higher level /home/username/virtualEnvName. Thanks so much.

Comment: Strange, I tested it on my system and just adding virtualEnvName to the path was enough. Anyways glad that it worked :)