# Hydrogen package in Atom IDE returns import error for all python packages e.g. numpy, nltk etc

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, nltk, atom-editor, hydrogen

I am new to using stackoverflow, so any advice for asking questions more clearly is welcomed.

I am trying to use hydrogen in atom to run python scripts on a mac M1 chip, which has worked for me in the past. After a clean laptop wipe, it no longer works. I receive the following errors:

For numpy, I get this: "Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed." ...

```
Original error was: dlopen(/Users/user/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-38-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/user/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-38-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/local/lib/_multiarray_umath.cpython-38-darwin.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/_multiarray_umath.cpython-38-darwin.so' (no such file)
```

And then, for nltk:

```
dlopen(/Users/user/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/regex/_regex.cpython-38-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/user/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/regex/_regex.cpython-38-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/local/lib/_regex.cpython-38-darwin.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/_regex.cpython-38-darwin.so' (no such file)
```

I have followed the all tutorials I can find online, but no luck.

If it helps, my paths for jupyter and python are the following, respectively:

/usr/local/share, /usr/bin/python3

Also, my python and numpy versions are up to date and the versions I expect.

Answer (score 0):

The way I made it work was to add at the top of my .py file:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Users/[username]/opt/anaconda3/envs/[your_virtual_env_name]/lib/python3.10/site-packages')
```

I combined the solution from the answer and a comment from [Tell Atom+Hydrogen to look in virtual enviromnment for packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63246991/tell-atomhydrogen-to-look-in-virtual-enviromnment-for-packages)